# Where to find databaseUrl in firebase

Tags: node.js, database, firebase, url, google-cloud-firestore

I was given only read-only access from my mentor,

so I was not able to view databaseUrl from config()

I was given service account private key file, which doesn't have `databaseUrl`, where to find database name in firestore?

Comment: `databaseURL` is a property of a Firebase Realtime Database. It is not used for Cloud Firestore. Please clarify which database you are targeting. Additionally, if your Firebase application is deployed on Firebase Hosting, you can pull the configuration from there at `https://<hosted domain>/__/firebase/init.json`.